# FB Login button cannot be clicked after ajax call: auth.revokeAuthorization

Tags: facebook, authentication, logout

I have a problem with my facebook login after ajax calls auth.revokeAuthorization
I am using the Javascript SDK.

The step to reproduce the error in my case is:

1. Click FB Login button
2. Allow to connect to FB App, followed by ajax calls by the system
3. The page does not reload, but the FB Login button becomes a HTMLElement with my facebook name along with the 'Disconnect from Facebook' button
4. If I click the 'Disconnect from Facebook' button, the ajax calls the auth.revokeAuthorization, then the HTML area returns to blue FB Login button just like no.1 above

However, this blue FB Login button after ajax logout cannot be clicked.
I need to refresh the page first to be able to click the button again, which is basically repeating from number 1 above.

I dont want the user to be logged out completely from Facebook.
I just want the user to get disconnected from my Facebook app completely and able to re-connect using the same login without reloading the page (ajax).

Why is this happening?
Is it because the $facebook->getUser() still exists?
If Yes, how can I clear the current user stored in my system. $facebook->destroySession does not help.
What is the solution for this?

Please help